# How can we find the distance between all residues in a PDB file?

Tags: protein-structure, pdb

If we have a PDB structrure, how can we find residues physically interacting with each other in space? I know that we must find the distance between residues and if the distance is less than 5-6 Angstrom, we say that residues are physically interacting. But how can we find the distance between all residues and how can we finally determine the distances between all residues? Is there a software or webserver for that?

Comment: These interaction may be already annotated in the PDB, see Connectivity Section and Connectivity Annotation Section in the [PDB spec](http://www.wwpdb.org/documentation/file-format-content/format33/v3.3.html).

Comment: One thing you're going to have to define for yourself is what you mean by "distance between residues". Do you mean closest atom pair? Closest heavyatom pair? Distance between C-alphas? The exact mechanism is probably going to be similar, regardless, but the details and the results will differ based on the definition.

Comment: I mean the distance between C-alphas

Comment: Is the Ring 2.0 webserver (http://protein.bio.unipd.it/ring/) good enough for this purpose?

Comment: If anyone is interested in speed benchmarks of distance calculations using various software, there are some at https://github.com/jgreener64/pdb-benchmarks. There are also example scripts for each software in that repository.

Answer (score 10):

If you need to process multiple files, you could use [Biopython](http://biopython.org/wiki/The_Biopython_Structural_Bioinformatics_FAQ) to parse a PDB structure.

```python
from Bio.PDB import PDBParser

# create parser
parser = PDBParser()

# read structure from file
structure = parser.get_structure('PHA-L', '1fat.pdb')

model = structure[0]
chain = model['A']

# this example uses only the first residue of a single chain.
# it is easy to extend this to multiple chains and residues.
for residue1 in chain:
    for residue2 in chain:
        if residue1 != residue2:
            # compute distance between CA atoms
            try:
                distance = residue1['CA'] - residue2['CA']
            except KeyError:
                ## no CA atom, e.g. for H_NAG
                continue
            if distance < 6:
                print(residue1, residue2, distance)
        # stop after first residue
        break
```

If you need to look at one structure, using a viewer perhaps would be easier. You could try [PyMOL](https://www.pymol.org/): ([how to measure distance](https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Distance)). There are other PDB viewers, some of which can work even through a browser.

Comment: Dear lakov, I installed Anaconda and Biopython packages and run the above code in PyCharm 5.0 and got the following error:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/VN7-592/PycharmProjects/untitled/sara.py", line 7, in <module>
    structure = parser.get_structure('PHA-L', '1FAT.pdb')

Comment: File "C:\Users\VN7-592\Desktop\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\Bio\PDB\PDBParser.py", line 81, in get_structure
    with as_handle(file, mode='rU') as handle:
  File "C:\Users\VN7-592\Desktop\Anaconda\lib\contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "C:\Users\VN7-592\Desktop\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\Bio\File.py", line 88, in as_handle
    with open(handleish, mode, **kwargs) as fp:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '1FAT.pdb'

Comment: You don't have the 1FAT.pdb file in the working directory, or your operating system is case sensitive.

Comment: But this gives only intermolecular distances? BioPython ignores crystal symmetry? In general, to check for contacts between residues X and Y one would need to calculate distance between X and the nearest symmetrical image of Y.

Answer (score 4):

Could you use CCP4's NCONT program? There's a GUI and a command line interface, whatever suits. You can specify which chains you want to target and interact with and set a cut off for distance. The bonus here is once you're in you have a nice suite of other structural tools to use.

If you're just doing it once, the GUI is friendly enough to work things out, if you're doing a batch then you can run it across several files via the command line.

[Download](http://www.ccp4.ac.uk/download/)

Comment: I have downloaded the program but I haven't been able to work with it yet. I'm trying to run it

Comment: @Sara what is it you're having a problem with?

Comment: It doesn't run with an error. The program says choose a project name and even when I have chosen a project name, again says choose a project name and stops running

Answer (score 2):

As part of a project me and some teammates did a [script](https://github.com/llrs/PYT-SBI) that outputs visual maps of distances between residues. It uses Biopython.

The module contact_map.py does what you are looking for. As an example, if you want to find the residues whose CA are below 5 you can run the following command:

```
python3 contact_map.py pdb1cd8.ent -a CA -CA 5
```

This will produce three files:

```
distance_map_pdb1cd8_CA.png # Heatmap of the distance between the residues
contact_map_pdb1cd8_CA.png # Black/White heatmap: If it is at that min distance
contact_map.log  # The actions taken
```

If you don't have downloaded already the pdb structue you can use the main module:

```
python3 cozmic.py real 1cd8 -a CA -CA 5
```

Comment: How it calculates distances? Inside the asymmetric unit only, or as the shortest distance between the two residues in the crystal (or in biological assembly)?

Comment: @marcin It calculates the distance between the C alpha (or beta if you chose so) between each residue in the file.

Comment: Usually, the file == asymmetric unit. If you'd like to find all contacts in [biological assembly](https://pdb101.rcsb.org/learn/guide-to-understanding-pdb-data/biological-assemblies) or in crystal you'd need to take the symmetry into account.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, maybe you want to contribute to the modules.

Comment: I'm working now on a [project](https://github.com/project-gemmi/gemmi/) that in the future may be competitive to Bio.PDB, but probably not this year yet :-)

Comment: I think Bio.PDB is being actively modified, but good luck with your work

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MDtraj](http://mdtraj.org/1.8.0/). The package is easy to install using Anaconda.

You can get the interacting residues using the following snippet (taken from http://mdtraj.org/1.6.2/examples/native-contact.html)

```
heavy_pairs = np.array(
    [(i,j) for (i,j) in combinations(heavy, 2)
        if abs(native.topology.atom(i).residue.index - \
               native.topology.atom(j).residue.index) > 3])

# compute the distances between these pairs in the native state
heavy_pairs_distances = md.compute_distances(native[0], heavy_pairs)[0]
# and get the pairs s.t. the distance is less than NATIVE_CUTOFF
native_contacts = heavy_pairs[heavy_pairs_distances < NATIVE_CUTOFF]
print("Number of native contacts", len(native_contacts))
```

Answer (score 0):

Distance between C-alphas can also be found using the [BioStructures.jl](https://github.com/BioJulia/BioStructures.jl) package in Julia:

```
using BioStructures
struc = read("1AKE.pdb", PDB)
calphas = collectatoms(struc['A'], calphaselector)
dm = DistanceMap(calphas)
```

Then `dm[5, 10]` gives `12.19677604943208` etc.

Other variations also work, see the [docs](https://biojulia.net/BioStructures.jl/stable/documentation.html#Spatial-calculations-1).