# How can I calculate the distances between two specific residues of a protein from a PDB file?

Tags: python, proteins, pdb

Suppose, we have a protein (`16PK`).

We are considering a 5-residue segment/window.

If we assume `ASN10` to be the `i`th residue, how can I calculate the following distances in **Python**?

1. from [i+2] to [i-2]
2. from [i+1] to [i-2]
3. from [i+2] to [i-1]

Next major question is, what would be the distances like if my segment/window is 7 or 9 residues long?

[image]

Comment: See this question for recommendations on a number of tools to calculate such distances: https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/783/how-can-we-find-the-distance-between-all-residues-in-a-pdb-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your $[i,j,k]$ coordinates in the PDB file are coordinates. You can readily compute [Euclidean distances](http://%20Euclidean%20distance%20-%20Wikipediahttps://en.wikipedia.org%20%E2%80%BA%20wiki%20%E2%80%BA%20Euclidean_distance) between any pair of coordinates as described in the wiki page:

$d(p,q)=\sqrt{(p_1-q_1)^2 + (p_2-q_2)^2 + (p_3-q_3)^2}.
$

[This resource](https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/moac/people/students/peter_cock/python/protein_contact_map/) suggests one such approach (code reproduced below in case that site stops existing):

```py
import Bio.PDB
import numpy

def calc_residue_dist(residue_one, residue_two) :
    """Returns the C-alpha distance between two residues"""
    diff_vector  = residue_one["CA"].coord - residue_two["CA"].coord
    return numpy.sqrt(numpy.sum(diff_vector * diff_vector))
```